# How to update javascript-viewmodel of a webpage with REST Post

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, rest, viewmodel

It there a way of updating viewmodel-data (= javascript-properties) on a webpage sitting on a host-server through REST Post sent by any application ? Or is there an $ajax function that can be activated from outside through a REST Post of some sort ? (or at least some sort of php-script that does update the viewmodel?)

The one thing I tried is to read data through an ajax-GET of a json-file that is sitting on the host-server (see example below...). Changing the json-file will then update the desired viewmodel-properties. But isnt't there a more direct way??

i.s. Application->REST(Post with URI)->$ajax(or other)->update-of-viewmodel

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',               
    url:'ScoreJSON/score.json',
    error: function(response) {
        self.viewModelData("myData")
        console.log('Error reading json-file...');
        // console.log(response);                   
    },
    success: function(response) {
        self.viewModelData(response.data)
        console.log('Data received: ');
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. To update data on a server, you need to send the data to the server (usually done through a POST or PATCH HTTP request). To get the updated data from the server you need to get the data from the server (usually done through the response of the POST/PATCH call, or via a separate GET request). That's how HTTP works.

Comment: I need to clarify: I would like to use [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) for dynamic data-binding. So far I have my webpage - I have my Knockout-data-binding (actually taking the data from a json-file with a 1-second polling). But I would like to leave apart the polling, json-file update and have some sort of REST-Post request instead that does the viewmodel-update directly (without json-file detour). Therefore, I am missing sending new data to my webpage and updating the viewmodel (i.e. javascript-properties) directly. How would I do that ?(or at least javascript-function-call) ???

Comment: There are many, many tutorials for getting all of these things working. Even the [Knockout site has a tutorial about this](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving). Why don't you do some of these tutorials, then come back when you have a specific question. This one is just too broad.

Comment: The tutorials show how to bind data. They show how to make $ajax Post/Get from within the javascript-code. But they do not show how to prepare your javascript to be ready for a Post-request from outside. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to update a simple viewmodel-property (i.e. javascript-variable) from an external App. How would you write the javascript to be responsive to such a call (i.e. API creation?)

Comment: Did you follow the link I put in my comment? Click through each of the steps? Because I don't think you could have read the text there and the links each of those point to, in two minutes. No, there isn't a ready-made copy-pasta there for you. You'll actually have to use your brain for this.

Comment: If you show me the link I appreciate it. Since none of them explain what I would like to achieve. The example only shows how to apply Knockout CLIENT-side. But I would like to update the javascript-viewmodel by an external Post request. (all clients having this webpage open would get an UI update dynamically).

Comment: Reading is fundamental. Click [this link](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving). Click the right arrow until you get to the "Step 4 of 5". READ the text and the code example there. If you can't comprehend that, I can't help you.

Comment: I read this. But it only explaines how the client makes changes on the server. I am not interested in this. I am interested in learning how to go the opposite way (i.e. how an external app updates the client's viewmodel)...

Comment: iKK, I believe I understand what you are asking. It does not fit into the other responder's template of how he knows and does things, but that does not negate the validity of your question. You would like the server to perform a RESTful POST or GET to your webpage, with data. You would like your webpage to receive this POST/GET in order to act on the data or signal it receives. I have not seen that done before except with Websockets as a data exchange method, instead of RESTful API's. HOWEVER, I'd love to see this, and could use it, if it were possible! Keep pushing, and report back!